# I want to enumerate a text from a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import os, glob

guessesTaken = 325
ha=0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
name = raw_input()
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken  <10000 and ha<6:
    print('Take a guess.') # There are four spaces in front of print.
    guess = raw_input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken - 25
    ha = ha+1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') # There are eight spaces in front of print.

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    ha = str(ha)
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + ha + ' guesses!')

    xa=len(name)



    f='f' 
    with open("f", "a") as myfile:


        myfile.write('name')     
        myfile.write(': ')
        myfile.write(name)
        myfile.write('          ')


        if len(name)==1:
            myfile.write(25 *' ')

        if len(name)==2:
            myfile.write(24 *' ')
        if len(name)==3:
            myfile.write(23 *' ')

        if len(name)==4:
            myfile.write(22 *' ')
        if len(name)==5:
            myfile.write(21 *' ')
        if len(name)==6:
            myfile.write(20 *' ')
        if len(name)==7:
            myfile.write(19 *' ')
        if len(name)==8:
            myfile.write(18 *' ')    

        if len(name)==9:
            myfile.write(17* ' ')

        if len(name)==10:
            myfile.write(16*' ')

        if len(name)==11:
            myfile.write(15*' ')
        if len(name)==12:
            myfile.write(14*' ')
        if len(name)==13:
            myfile.write(13*' ')        
        if len(name)==14:
            myfile.write(12*' ')
        if len(name)==15:
            myfile.write(11*' ')
        if len(name)==16:
            myfile.write(10*' ')
        if len(name)==17:
            myfile.write(9*' ')
        if len(name)==18:
            myfile.write(8*' ')

        if len(name)==19:
            myfile.write(7*' ')

        if len(name)==20:
            myfile.write(6*' ')
        if len(name)==21:
            myfile.write(5*' ')

        if len(name)==22:
            myfile.write(4*' ')       
        myfile.write('score')
        myfile.write(': ')
        myfile.write(guessesTaken)
        myfile.write('\n\n')





with open(f) as myfile:
        print myfile.read()
```

I want to appear like:
1.name          score
2.name          score
3.name          score
.
.
.
.
.
.

I don't know how to enumerate before name.

And I want to sort the score like a record. 
Thank for help.

Comment: I've added the `sort()`function to the my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this, I used the append mode(`'a'`) here to append the new lines at the bottom of the file. I am leaving the formatting to you.:

```
with open('data1.txt','a') as f,open('data1.txt') as f1:
    lines=[x.strip() for x in f1]        #read the lines
    num=len(lines)+1
    f.write("{0}.{1:22s}{2}\n".format((num),name,ha))
```

**Edit:**

I missed the sorting part, so here's your sorting function:

```
def sortfile(fil):
    with open(fil,'r+') as f:
        lines=[x.strip() for x in f]
        lines.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split()[-1]))   #sort as per score
        #print(lines)
        f.truncate(0)          #empty the file
        f.seek(0)              #move the cursor back to the start of the file
        for i,x in enumerate(lines):
            ind=x.index('.')           #fetch the index of '.'
            #print ("{0}.{1}\n".format(i+1,x[ind+1:]))
            f.write("{0}.{1}\n".format(i+1,x[ind+1:]))

sortfile('data1.txt')    #call the function whenever you want to sort the file as per scores
```

Comment: @user1617320 just tested this in python 2.7 too and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

A bit less complex:

```
myfile = open('data.txt', 'r+a')
lines = myfile.readlines()
myfile.write(str(len(lines)+1)+'.'+name+' '+str(score)+'\n')
```

*EDIT*

forgot to add a \n arg...at the end XD